# Container not disposing transient components

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-windsor, nservicebus

I'm not sure whether this is more of an NServiceBus issue, a Windsor issue, or just my own stupidity problem - but I'm experiencing a memory leak which seems to point to lots of transient components still hanging around.

This is how I set up NServiceBus with Windsor, inside my `IWantCustomInitialization.Init` method:

```cs
var cont = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();
cont.Register(
    Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(cont));     

Configure.With()
    .CastleWindsorBuilder(cont)
    .DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCommandAttribute), false).GetLength(0) > 0)
    .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyEventAttribute), false).GetLength(0) > 0)
    .DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith(".LocalMessages"))
    .XmlSerializer()
    .Log4Net()
    .IsolationLevel(System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
    .UseNHibernateTimeoutPersister()
    .RunTimeoutManager()
    .Sagas()
    .NHibernateSagaPersister()
    .DisableRavenInstall();

cont.Register(
    Component.For<ISessionFactory>().Named("ABC").LifeStyle.Singleton.UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
{
    return Fluently.Configure().Database(() =>
        {
            return MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.UseOuterJoin()
            .ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ABCData"))
            .ShowSql();
        }
    ).Mappings((m) =>
        {
            AddABCMappingsOnly(m.FluentMappings);
        })
    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns(cfg);
            var sv = new SchemaValidator(cfg);
            sv.Validate();
        })
    .BuildSessionFactory();
}));

cont.Register(
    Component.For(typeof(IClientLookup), typeof(ICountryLookup), typeof(IOtherLookupLookup)).LifeStyle.Transient.ImplementedBy<ABCDataLookup>().DependsOn(
Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(ISessionFactory), "ABC")));
```

What I find is that, after some period of uptime (say, 2 hours pushing through messages as much as possible), I have thousands of `ABCDataLookup` components lurking around, and so far as I can see, the only thing holding onto these components is the Windsor container (*so, presumably, it still thinks something else is using these components?*)

Some of my issues may arise from the fact that NServiceBus takes responsibility for registering some components in the container and/or performing resolution, so I'm not able to cleanly see whether the registrations look correct.

**Is there something I've done wrong/stupid in my registration?**

I'm already having to do one thing that looks wrong:

```
cont.Register(
    Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(cont));
```

because NServiceBus registers one `ISessionFactory` in the container for use by `IFindSagas` implementations. But I have another component that implements `IWantToRunWhenTheBusStarts` that wants to obtain the "ABC" `ISessionFactory`, and I couldn't work out how to make that work between NServiceBus and Windsor.

The other components that expect to have `ABCDataLookup` instances injected are Sagas, and again, I'm not able to really see how NServiceBus is registering/instantiating them.

If there's any extra code or config that needs to be shown, please shout.

My Packages.config:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="3.0.0.4001" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor" version="3.0.0.4001" targetFramework="net45" />
<!-- irrelevant -->
  <package id="FluentNHibernate" version="1.3.0.733" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Iesi.Collections" version="3.2.0.4000" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="log4net" version="1.2.10" targetFramework="net45" />
<!-- irrelevant -->
  <package id="NHibernate" version="3.3.2.4000" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NServiceBus" version="3.3.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NServiceBus.CastleWindsor" version="3.3.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NServiceBus.Host" version="3.3.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NServiceBus.Interfaces" version="3.3.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NServiceBus.NHibernate" version="3.3.8" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Did you read this: http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor.aspx

Comment: @Marwijn - I have read it, but it hasn't offered me any insight, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you check the number of Sagas instances against ABCDataLookup instances. If it is matching then it is Sagas to blame for holding referencies, not windsor container

Comment: I started an issue about this: https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/1206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have fixed quite a few things to do with disposing of components properly in v4, see https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/commit/baa9624517d1083e3cfa681e8598f66ccfbf741b

Also the `ISessionFactory` should be implemented as a UoW, see our internal implementation for inspiration [here](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/nhibernate/UnitOfWork/NServiceBus.UnitOfWork.NHibernate/UnitOfWorkManager.cs)

Comment: Could you point me towards the bug(s) that cause the issue please?

Comment: We have fixed quite a few things to do with disposing of components properly in v4, see https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/commit/baa9624517d1083e3cfa681e8598f66ccfbf741b